# Parsing CultureInfo.InvariantCulture identifier

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo, invariantculture

Let's say we have the following config:

```
{
  "en": "something for english language",
  "de": "something for german language",
  ""  : "something language independent"
}
```

By [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=net-6.0) the identifier of Invariant culture is empty string, but I do not like this because it can be quite easily interpreted as no data. Is there any standard or defacto ID which represents invariant culture? I was thinking something like `*` or `inv`, but I would rather took something less subjective.

Comment: `en-us` should be the invariant culture. But can't you just use anything you like eg. `myFancyTag` and in code `if (tag == "myFancyTag") cultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;` ?!?

Comment: You just pointed to the docs that say the `standard or defacto ID`is the empty string. Which makes *far* more sense than a custom identifier. ` interpreted as no data` precisely - in the default case, where no explicit identifier data is provided, use the Invariant culture

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - but OP said `but I do not like this`

Comment: @RandRandom in that case the question should be closed as opinion-based. I'm pretty sure most people won't like a custom tag instead of the standard identifier. Even the OP won't like it after a week or two when they forget what they did, or start working on another library and wonder why they get invalid culture errors due to some weird config value nobody remembers using

Comment: @RandRandom not to mention third-party libraries that would choke if they encountered the custom culture tag

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - agree that the question is close worthy, because I can't think of anythint else then the answer "you don't like the identifier, than use your own which you like" but that answer seems so obvious that I struggle to believe that this is the answer OP is looking for, so the question seems not clear enough

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) : someone has a problem X and assumes Y is the solution. When that doesn't work, they ask for the assumed solution Y instead of the actual problem X. What is the *actual* problem? It sounds like the *actual* problem is how to load localized resources with fallback. Fallback doesn't mean using the invariant culture. It could mean using English resources though. That's already supported in .NET in various ways, all of which can be customized to use alternate resource sources.

Comment: .NET Framework and .NET Core, both desktop and web app stacks, allow resource localization *and* using custom resource providers. The [Localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0) page for example shows how to use a custom resource provider. There's no need for a custom provider to specify a fallback culture. In the rare case where none of the existing resources can be used as fallback, the *provider* can map `""` to any key it wants

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos interpret as no data I ment like null value. I know it is not, but still, from the config point of view they are quite close and in that sense it can confuse the one who will need to make it. I don't see it as intuitive enough.But, on the other side, more than I thinking, more I see "" is better solution than something totally mine. I checked `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(String)` documentation and it follows its owns Windows standard and BCP 47 one. In none of them invariant culture is mentioned.  Probably this why empty string is chosen for for ID.

Comment: The default empty is perfectly fine. What is the actual problem though? Fallback doesn't mean invariant and most of the time, it's not the invariant culture. This sounds like localization, not configuration. If you need to create a custom resource provider you can easily map `""` or `null` to whatever storage key you want. It's far more common to use an existing language as a fallback though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos concretely I need to acquire some data from external services. In some cases I need to call language specific endpoint (each language has it's own endpoint) in some cases I can call single endpoint for all languages. I don't see this case as a fallback because there is no fallback for language specific versions. And, on the other side, config would look quite more complex. In that case, example is not perfect representation of what I want. I should probably make to config examples. One with single invariant culture and the other with concrete ones.

Comment: There is another case which I don't like. If I wanted to use invariant culture in composite key with `:` delimiter, keys would looks like this: `:`, `bar:` , `:foo` , `::`. But, at the end it is still technically valid.

Comment: That's *very* different from what you wrote in the question. For starters, the standard way of specifying a language is to use the `Accept-Language` header. Browsers already do that based on the user's settings, so if the remote services also accept `Accept-Language` you could just pass the user's choice. A missing `Accept-Language` is quite valid. `Accept-Language: *` on the other hand means `all`. Localized endpoints have nothing to do with an implementation language's defaults though

Comment: If you want a mapping from country or language codes to URLs, why use CultureInfo tags in the first place? You can use only the two-letter ISO codes (which do match the CultureInfo tags), along with a `Default` or `Fallback` or whatever name you want. Unless you use `Thread.CurrentCulture` to detect the current request's language ? In that case just map `""` to something else.

Comment: I do not have control how external URLs works. In one case, on one endpoint I get results for all languages, in other case I need to call different endpoint for different language. There is no HTTP header involved in neither of cases.